# Bisection to find roots in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, numerical-methods

I have written a short C/C++ code finding root by bisection. (This is a simple iterative numerical method allowing to find the root of an equation i.e. x such that f(x) = 0). [Bisection Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method%22Bisection%20method%20on%20Wikipedia%22)

The header simply consists of guards and of the following lines:

```
#include <functional>
double bisection(double x1, 
                 double x2, 
                 double e, 
                 std::function<double(double)>& f);
```

In order to get plain C code, the `std::function<double(double)>` in the signature of the function has to be turned into a `double(*f)(double)`;

I have **two questions**.

The first is if this code can be improved (minor improvements). 
The second is if recursion is a good choice.

```
namespace { 
    double bisection(double x1, 
                     double x2, 
                     double e, 
                     std::function<double(double)>& f, 
                     double fx1, 
                     double fx2){
        double mid = x1*0.5 + x2*0.5;
        if (x2 - x1 < e)
            return mid;
        double fmid = f(mid);
        if ((fmid>0.0) == (fx1 > 0.0))
            return bisection(mid, x2, e, f, fmid, fx2);
        return bisection(x1, mid, e, f, fx1, fmid);
    }
}

double bisection(double x1, 
                 double x2, 
                 double e, 
                 std::function<double(double)>& f){
    double fx1 = f(x1);
    double fx2 = f(x2);
    return bisection(x1, x2, e, f, fx1, fx2);
}
```

An example of main using my code is:

```
#include "bisection.hpp"
int main(){
    bisection(0.0, 1.0, 1.0E-6, [](double x){return x*x-0.5;})

    return 0;
}
```

please notice that x1 and x2 are expected to be ordered: x1 < x2. Moreover the user should be aware of the fact that there will be a log_2((x_2-x_1)/tolerance) calls stack.

Comment: Although this is probably well known, could you please provide us usage example? Small `.cpp` file with all includes and `main()` would be great. Usually include directives might be reviewed too.

Answer (score 4):

1. If any of `fmid`, `fx1` or `fx2` are zero (or close to zero), you should stop, since you already found an answer. That's also in Wikipedia's example algorithm. Even for the constant function `f = [](double){return 0;}`, your code will still continue and take a total of \$ \log_2 \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{\varepsilon}\right)\$ calls.
2. Your recursion [cannot get transformed into a loop by GCC](https://www.godbolt.org/#z: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%2BrlWvlVNVzDVp7GGqQDRjSS5SUgsaQWGuoaSafj8VTCMTuOS0GsEevlisAaxAlwslakABYa3WpA3SE2pDXBCAx33Z%2BXSHBYEg0PZnHhQmQKBBd/vDyBgB5ZKRtAeCJhiMuIEF%2B6QIsZiABPaQ90i7xwsAQADyLAMN%2B66kFg9isMAoSvvgoIKgAbk4r6YMk0QiPeP41go94MK%2BBDEHg9j9hWzBsCgra8IweBBMukAVqgzicsuUjfEBshLqI4iSLQ5FVtOr4LskAAcIzfCME6qMAyDIKoHjnLIHy4IQJA3LIaSaKge4Hg%2BGn8aoLa8PwvZkUOI5jgRk5CRBC5LiupBrg2DLjlwtlzvZTnmaQKGPh0IATkAA%3D%3D%3D). The recursive algorithm looks nice, but since we end up with \$ \log_2 \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{\varepsilon}\right)\$ calls. An iterative variant is easy to write, so I'd use that one.
3. Not only must \$x_1 <x_2 \$, but also \$f(x_1) f(x_2) < 0\$, that is, the signs of \$f(x_1)\$ and \$f(x_2)\$ must differ. Otherwise your algorithm might not find the root. I only mention this because you wrote that \$x_1\$ and \$x_2\$ are expected to be ordered, but that's not enough.

Other than that, I strongly suggest you to use braces even for single statement `if`s, as missing braces have been a source of errors too often.

Alternatively a little bit more whitespace in your function can make it a lot easier to read:

```
namespace { 
double bisection(double x1, 
                 double x2, 
                 double e, 
                 std::function<double(double)>& f, 
                 double fx1, 
                 double fx2){

    const double mid = x1*0.5 + x2*0.5;
    const double fmid = f(mid);

    if (x2 - x1 < e || fmid == 0.0) {
        return mid;
    }


    if ((fmid > 0.0) == (fx1 > 0.0)) {
        return bisection(mid, x2, e, f, fmid, fx2);
    } else {
        return bisection(x1, mid, e, f, fx1, fmid);
    }
}
}
```

I would use the ternary operator though instead of `if`/`else`, but that's only a style question. But then again, I would write this in an iterative way, since we don't need an additional helper.

Comment: I was aware of point 3, I didn't list it because this is a "bug" of the method itself while the fact that they are expected ordered is an implementation detail. In any case thanks for pointing it out. And thanks for points 1 and 2 too.

Answer (score 3):

- Temporary can't bind to a non-const reference in standard C++ (MSVC++ will compile it because of compiler extension): make `f` a const reference
- Const correctness: use const wherever possible
- Some temporary variables can be avoided. E.g., `fmid`
- Is there a reason you do `x1 * 0.5 + x2 * 0.5` instead of `(x1 + x2) * 0.5`? If for some numerical reasons, it's fine. Otherwise, I find the latter more intuitive
- You don't really need `fx2`
- Recursion can indeed be more both more costly (if not optimized by the compiler) and more difficult to read.

Given all of the above considerations, here's a simple non-recursive version:

```
double bisection(
    double x1,
    double x2,
    const double e,
    const std::function<double(double)>& f)
{
    while(x2 - x1 >= e)
    {
        const double mid = (x1 + x2) * 0.5;
        if((f(mid) > 0.0) == (f(x1) > 0.0))
            x1 = mid;
        else
            x2 = mid;
    }
    return (x1 + x2) * 0.5;
}
```

And here's the version that caches `f(x1)`:

```
double bisection(
    double x1,
    double x2,
    const double e,
    const std::function<double(double)>& f)
{
    double fx1 = f(x1);
    while(x2 - x1 >= e)
    {
        const double mid = (x1 + x2) * 0.5;
        const double fmid = f(mid);
        if((fmid > 0.0) == (fx1 > 0.0))
        {
            x1 = mid;
            fx1 = fmid;
        }
        else
        {
            x2 = mid;
        }
    }
    return (x1 + x2) * 0.5;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in producing a version caching f(x1). Offering this version is of capital importance IMO.

Comment: Would you consider if(fmid==0) break; ?

Comment: About the strange x1 * 0.5 + x2 * 0.5 I've used it in order to avoid any risk of overflow. I am not sure this is of help in 99.99999 percent of use cases.

Comment: @jimifiki Ah, I see. Thanks for the explanation. As for the `if(fmid==0)`, it depends on the usage patterns. IMO it's not worth to have an extra comparison for this very rare case. In other words it's a trade-off: optimized function in 0.001% vs. slightly slower in 99.999%.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions from other answers, idiomatic C++ would use a template parameter for the function object type, rather than `std::function`.  `std::function` is great when you need late binding of functions at runtime for whatever reason, but it's also a tremendous optimization barrier.  I suspect this will be much faster:

```
template <typename Func>
double bisection(double x1, double x2, double e, Func f)
{
    double fx1 = f(x1);
    double mid = x1 * 0.5 + x2 * 0.5;
    while (x2 - x1 >= e) {
        double fmid = f(mid);
        if ((fx1 > 0.0) == (fmid > 0.0)) {
            x1 = mid;
            fx1 = fmid;
        } else {
            x2 = mid;
        }
        mid = x1 * 0.5 + x2 * 0.5;
    }
    return mid;
}
```

(Credit to [AMA's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/195965/30863) for most of that implementation.)

You could even make it slightly more general by parameterizing the value type instead of assuming `double`.

Comment: You would also use an `Func && f` usually. However, `std::function<…>::operator()(…)` can get optimized  by the compiler in some circumstances, so it's not "much faster" in general.

Comment: A naive question: why is `std::function<…>::operator()(…)` likely to be slower than a pointer to function? I would be grateful to anyone sharing a link to any relevant content.

Comment: My understanding is that common`std::function` implementations will need *two* indirections, not one: first to handle the various types of function that can be wrapped such as function objects, then another to actually call the pointed-to function.  But even one function pointer is much slower than zero.